# Variable binding in PHP ADOdb

Tags: php, binding, parameters, sql-injection, adodb-php

Does ADOdb do data sanitation or escaping within the same functionality by default? Or am I just confusing it with Code Igniter's built-in processes?

Does binding variables to parameters in ADOdb for PHP prevent SQL injection in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct - bound parameters are not vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: He meant specifically the adodb-php library.

Answer (score 4):

yes, you pass the array of parameters.

```
$rs = $db->Execute('select * from table where val=?', array('10'));
```

Rest of their docs can be found [here](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/#docs):