# Adodb, escaping quotes?

Tags: php, sql, escaping, quotes, adodb

I am using adodb with php.  I need to insert html into my database, and need to know the best method to escape the quotes before inserting it into the database?  I tried using pg_escape_string() but it still does not seem to insert.

What is the best method to do this?

Answer (score 5):

The best method is to use a parameterized query. See here to get started:

- SO question: [Calling Stored Procedure using ADOdb in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308790/calling-stored-procedure-using-adodb-in-php)
- SO question: [Binding variables to parameters in ADOdb for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76359/binding-variables-to-parameters-in-adodb-for-php)
- [ADOdb Library for PHP - documentation](http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm)

Comment: I am not sure I understand how this will help in escaping.

Comment: @Nic: But that is the whole *point* of parameterized queries. You don't need any escaping. You pass the raw string into the parameter, and that's it.

Comment: Ok, I guess even after looking at those posts I am still every confused how to use parameterized queries.

Comment: $sql = "INSERT tbl (id, html) VALUES (?, ?)"; 
$results = $this->db->Execute($sql, array($id_val, $html_string));

Answer (score 2):

```
$conn = &ADONewConnection('access');

$var = $conn->qstr("Clean");
```

Comment: Sometimes [addQ](http://adodb.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=v5:reference:connection:addq) is better alternative